# How to play a video inside a specified container from its URL?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want to play a video in the `<div class="videoPlayer">` when I click on one of the links with the respective URL, i.e. without opening a new tab. How do I do this in JavaScript?

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Playing a video</h1>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <nav>
      <ul id="video">
        <li><a href="video/1.mp4">Video 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="video/2.mp4">Video 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="video/3.mp4">video 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="videoPlayer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) documentation and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement) documentation and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement) documentation

Answer (score 0):

I would make three `<video src="video/1.mp4" controls></video>` tags inside of the video player div and then have them `display: none;` until the user clicks on one of the links. Then have a javascript function change the `display` to `block` for that video.

When the user clicks on a new link, make it also turn all the other video players to `display: none;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Was fixing to try it.  Let ya know.

Comment: No it didn't...there are no tutorials on how to do this on the video tag though a serious of list?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  var vid = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  console.log(vid);
  var player = $('li').on("click",(function() {
   playVid();
  }));
});

function playVid(){
 $("video").css('display', 'block');
 
};

Comment: It shows all videos when  i try to hide the others in the video it doesn't work.

Comment: When you set one video's display to block, do you also set all the other video's displays to none.